# Screen shatter animation for Unity / Vuforia AR Mobile App

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am a Unity/Vuforia noob and I am currently building an Augmented Reality app for iOS / Android using C#.

I would like to create a phone / tablet screen shatter animation.

I have used the Unity canvas / panel to create a static image like this:

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/4E6_yKxtYn4L8-AQRPEReOVNWiBjoMvWIx5rdbC6V44LIw5ABSK57RPuHXAf6rFTtiQ=h900-rw

But I would then like it to animate the glass to fall downwards and then to disappear, like the first effect here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6WYsz4iSvQ

I have purchased some breaking glass assets if that helps:

Breakable Glass Complete Solution
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/39717

I cannot get a suitable animation to appear on the canvas / UI?

Is this even possible?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Open the `BreakableGlassDemoScene.unity` scene from your project and run the editor.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I have solved this by playing around with the camera location.